# Use different group in bubblewrap

Tags: linux, bash, dac, bubblewrap

my user belongs to some groups:

```
$ id
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),1003(shared)
```

Now I have a program running in bwrap/bubblewrap.
I can tell the program to create files as a specified group, but in bubblewrap all groups are truncated:

```
$ bwrap --ro-bind / / id
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),65534(nobody)
```

For me, it would be ok if the program in bwrap has a group I can specify, e.g.
`bwrap --gid 1003`, but this also creates files as group 1000.

Is there anything I can do to change the main group to another group I belong to? (Probably before the bwrap call)

Comment: `newgrp shared`?

Comment: Thank you very much! Your comment helped me to find `sg`, which is usable in scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `newgrp` command can be used to get a shell, in scripts `sg` can be used.

(Thank you to Cyrus)